# How to format html form checkbox URL parameters to \?var1=X,Y,Z

Tags: forms, url, checkbox, parameters

I have a html form that sends the parameters of a checkbox group (X,Y,Z) to the URL like this:

```
https://mycompany.com/?var1=X&var1=Y&var1=Z
```

I want to change the way the form sends the variables so the URL is formatted like this:

```
https://mycompany.com/?var1=X,Y,Z
```

I’m happy to use any type of code but prefer twig.

Any thoughts or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Being a newbie at this level, I’ve tried to guess various twig and Java scripts with nothing delivering the ideal outcome above.

Here is the basic form code:

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="checkbox" name="var1" id="rx" value="X">
<label>Label X</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="var1" id="ry" value="Y">
<label>Label Y</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="var1" id="rz" value="Z">
<label>Label Z</label>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<button type="get" class="button button1">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry for the poorly formatted question - I'm a newbie. I think its fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use `JavaScript` in order to change the default behavior of the form and rewrite the URL yourself.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let form = document.getElementById('myform');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let checkboxes = [];
    document.getElementsByName('var1').forEach(function(checkbox) {
      if (checkbox.checked) checkboxes.push(checkbox.value);
    });
    window.location = '?var1=' + checkboxes.join(',');
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox" name="var1" id="rx" value="X">
    <label>Label X</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="var1" id="ry" value="Y">
    <label>Label Y</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="var1" id="rz" value="Z">
    <label>Label Z</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="button button1">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

FYI: `get` is not a valid value for the attribute `type` of a button - [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#attr-type)

Comment: Hi @darkbee, could you please help with my follow-up question if you have a moment? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75532504/how-to-format-html-form-checkbox-url-parameters-to-var1-x-y-zvar2-a-b-cvar3