# How to get checkbox parameters into URL and formate like \?var1=X,Y,Z&var2=A,B,C&var3=1,2,3

Tags: javascript, forms, url, checkbox, url-parameters

I have developed a job board and need to give the user 3 types of filters:

- Job Type

  - 1
  - 2
  - 3...
- Region Name

  - 1
  - 2
  - 3...
- Salary Range

  - 1
  - 2
  - 3...

I want to send the results of a user checking any combination of boxes to the URL and have it formatted like /?JT=1,3&RN=2,3&SR=1

With the help of @darkbee I have this code which works for one variable, but I didn't have the foresight to ask how to do it for three:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let form = document.getElementById('myform');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let checkboxes = [];
    document.getElementsByName('JT').forEach(function(checkbox) {
      if (checkbox.checked) checkboxes.push(checkbox.value);
    });
    window.location = '?JT=' + checkboxes.join(',');
  });
});
```

```
<form id="myform">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox" name="JT" value="1">
    <label>Label X</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="JT" value="2">
    <label>Label Y</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="JT" value="3">
    <label>Label Z</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="button button1">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I tried to solve the problem with three separate forms, each with DarkBee's modified code, but I could get to work was one at a time - that is, I couldn't choose checkboxes from multiple filter options.

If anyone can help, I'd be very happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple checkboxes, and your code works for one checkbox, you should try to make a loop. To deal with URL parameters, you can use the [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) JS class. Example with your code:

```js
let urlParams = new URLSearchParams();
for (let checkboxName of ['JT', 'RN', 'SR']) {
  let checkboxes = [];
  document.getElementsByName(checkboxName).forEach(function(checkbox) {
    if (checkbox.checked) checkboxes.push(checkbox.value);
  });
  urlParams.append(checkboxName, checkboxes.join(','));
}
window.location = '?' + urlParams.toString();
```

Here is the complete example of your code:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  let form = document.getElementById('myform');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let urlParams = new URLSearchParams();
    for (let checkboxName of ['JT', 'RN', 'SR']) {
      let checkboxes = [];
      document.getElementsByName(checkboxName).forEach(function(checkbox) {
        if (checkbox.checked) checkboxes.push(checkbox.value);
      });
      urlParams.append(checkboxName, checkboxes.join(','));
    }
    console.log('Navigate to: ?' + urlParams.toString());
    //window.location = '?' + urlParams.toString();
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <legend>Job Type</legend>
    <input id="JT-1" type="checkbox" name="JT" value="1" />
    <label for="JT-1">Label X</label>
    <input id="JT-2" type="checkbox" name="JT" value="2" />
    <label for="JT-2">Label Y</label>
    <input id="JT-3" type="checkbox" name="JT" value="3" />
    <label for="JT-3">Label Z</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <legend>Region Name</legend>
    <input id="RN-1" type="checkbox" name="RN" value="1" />
    <label for="RN-1">Label X</label>
    <input id="RN-2" type="checkbox" name="RN" value="2" />
    <label for="RN-2">Label Y</label>
    <input id="RN-3" type="checkbox" name="RN" value="3" />
    <label for="RN-3">Label Z</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="form-group">
    <legend>Salary Range</legend>
    <input id="SR-1" type="checkbox" name="SR" value="1" />
    <label for="SR-1">Label X</label>
    <input id="SR-2" type="checkbox" name="SR" value="2" />
    <label for="SR-2">Label Y</label>
    <input id="SR-3" type="checkbox" name="SR" value="3" />
    <label for="SR-3">Label Z</label>
  </fieldset>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="button button1">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I'm getting a loop that stops the page from loading fully - should there be something else in the "for (let checkboxName of ['JT', 'RN', 'SR'])"

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a full working snippet you can play with.

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you for your time and willingness to help!